# ack results do not contain newlines in zsh

Tags: zsh, ack

I use zsh as my default shell

When I do a simple ack command like

```
$ ack a_string
```

it does not insert a newline between the lines that match. So they all get jumbled up like

```
a_string is on this linethis is another line a_string is onand a third a_string line
```

Bash displays the results correctly:

```
a_string is on this line
this is another line a_string is on
and a third a_string line
```

Comment: On my machine (Ubuntu 14.04, ack 2.12, zsh 5.0.5) it seems to work without issue. Which versions of `ack` and `zsh` are you using? And does the same thing happen in a *zsh* started with `zsh -f`?

Comment: `zsh` is known to alias `ack`. Check `which ack`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zsh` does not alias `ack`. Perhaps `oh-my-zsh` does that...

[...]

the easiest way to debug something like this is to:

1. See what is it that you are running as 'ack': `which ack`
2. Run zsh without loading *any* config file of yours, executing 'ack':
   `zsh -f -c 'cd test-dir && ack a_string'`

You can also run `which -a ack` to see all "ack"s present in your path...

Comment: Thanks! I did have an alias to ack that I didn't know about previously. Your suggestion to `which -a ack` helped me to solve that issue